# Illicit gay relationship between children of Starfleet officers

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, fan-fiction

Trying to recall which episode of which fan series featured a plot involving a human and vulcan, both children of Starfleet officers, trying to work out what to do about their relationship (because it would put their parents in a difficult position, rather than their being gay which no-one cares about).

Comment: You're gonna have to try to remember more than that, or this question will probably get closed. Names of the main characters? I'm assuming it takes place on Earth? Any major events occur that we can use as reference points to narrow down the search? Perhaps you can remember which website you read it on, even that would help a bit.

Comment: @Dragon: If so, please click on the checkmark by the voting buttons for the answer to accept it.

Comment: Turns out most of my information was incorrect -- they're both human, only one of them is related to an officer, and he's a nephew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an episode of the James Cawley productions of [***Star Trek: New Voyages***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_New_Voyages) previously branded *Star Trek: Phase II.*

The episode in question is a two-parter : *Blood & Fire*.

[**Snippet**](http://stexpanded.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_and_Fire,_Part_1_(STNV_episode)):

> Peter comes to speak with Kirk in an official way, and asks him why he has taken him out of the team, and he will have to ask a transfer to avoid favoritisms, beside his future husband, lieutenant Alex Freeman, if Kirk wants to marry them. Kirk surprises and says that they will talk about the wedding when finalizing the mission, and concedes Peter to join to the mission. Kirk discovers that he was the only in knowing it.

Comment: What does *Kirk discovers that he was the only in knowing it* mean?